# Browse file dialog

Tags: asp.net

How can I add a file browse functionality on my asp.net web form ?
I have a similar button in my winforms app and now I need it on asp.net my web page.
FileUpload control is used to select and post file to a web server, I just need to select file path/name without sending file.

Should I add some JS to delete FORM item before doing POST or any other simplier solution exists ?

Comment: What will you do after saving the path/name?

Comment: I just need to get file path from web form and save it to DB table. I don't need actual file POSTed. We use Telerik, so I think I can find a soolution using 3-rd part control. Can I do it asp.net/html built in tags ?

Comment: You can use javascript to get selected path and then in page postback , don't save file / discard posted file.

Comment: it is inconvinient to wait for an upload of big files. I just need only file name and browse dialog (box) :)

Comment: Posted answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this.

1. You can use `asp:FileUpload` , when user selects a file, you need to get that path using this - `document.getElementById("fileeupload_id").value`. Save this value to hidden field , say with id `hdn`.
2. Reset file selection using this - `document.getElementById("fileeupload_id").value = ""`.
3. So that, when page will be posted, you file will not be posted,rather filename will be posted as `hdn`.Use `Request.Form["hdn"]` to get selected file path.